# BrowserSync task in my Gulp process works only once then it looks like stuck. How to make it work correctly?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Hi I try to make some experiments with Gulp. I defined tasks for css and js and create some watch function. Now I would like to run hot reload but I have issue with that. Everything looks fine and also works only once. When I run gulp command and change js or scss file first time, the changes are applied and immediately are shows in browser. But when I change the files second time the whole process looks like stuck somewhere...

Here is my output in terminal:

```
λ gulp
[14:28:47] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive\Desktop\gulp\GulpLearning\gulpfile.js
[14:28:47] Starting 'default'...
[14:28:47] Starting 'style'...
[14:28:47] Starting 'js'...
[14:28:47] Starting 'browserSyncTask'...
[14:28:47] Starting 'watch'...
[Browsersync] 2 files changed (style.min.css.map, style.min.css)
[14:28:47] Finished 'style' after 223 ms
[Browsersync] 2 files changed (index.min.js.map, index.min.js)
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 2 events)
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.56.1:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
```

Here is my code:

```
// Require packages (from package json)
const gulp = require( 'gulp' );
const rename = require( 'gulp-rename' );
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const babelify = require('babelify');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// CONSTS
const styleSRC = 'src/scss/style.scss';
const styleDIST = './dist/css/';
const styleWATCH = 'src/scss/**/*.scss';

const jsSRC = 'index.js';
const jsFolder = 'src/js/';
const jsDIST = './dist/js/';
const jsWATCH = 'src/js/**/*.js';
const jsFiles = [jsSRC];

/**
 * Gulp task for compile,compress, 
 * create source map and add autoprefixes 
 * for styles.
 * @returns 
 */
function style() {
    return gulp.src( styleSRC )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( sass({
            errorLogToConsole: true, 
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
        }) )
        .on( 'error', console.error.bind( console ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer({ 
            overrideBrowserslist: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%'], 
            cascade: false
        }) )
        .pipe( rename( { suffix: ".min" } ) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( styleDIST ) )
        .pipe( browserSync.stream() );
}
exports.style = style;

/**
 * Gulp task for compile Javascripts
 * @returns 
 */
function js( ){
        return jsFiles.map(function ( entry ){
            // 1. browserify
            return browserify({
                entries: [jsFolder + entry],
            })
            // 2. transform babelify [env] (env is set up in package.json)
            .transform( babelify, {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']} )
            // 3. bundle
            .bundle()
            // 4. source
            .pipe( source( entry ) )
            // 5. rename .min
            .pipe( rename( { extname: ".min.js" } ) )
            // 6. buffer
            .pipe( buffer() )
            // 7. sourcemap
            .pipe( sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps:true }) )
            // 8. uglify
            .pipe( uglify() )
            // 9. write sourcemaps
            .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './' ) )
            // 10. dist
            .pipe( gulp.dest( jsDIST ) )
            .pipe( browserSync.stream() );
        })
}
exports.js = js;

/**
 * Task which start server and 
 * apply hot-reload for changes in FE
 * @returns 
 */
function browserSyncTask(){
    return browserSync.init({
        
        // This works only for localhost if we need specific URL we need specify further
        // For more information watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDjE_LCHbuI&list=PLriKzYyLb28lp0z-OMB5EYh0OHaKe91RV&index=8&ab_channel=AlessandroCastellani
         server: {
           baseDir: "./",
         },
         // reloadDelay: 1000 // Add a 1 second delay to the reload function
         injectChanges: false // Disable the injectChanges option

        //open: false,
        //injectChanges: true,
        //proxy: 'https://some-url.dev',
        //https: {
            //key: './key.pem',  // Need to specify key and cer
            //cert: './cert.pem' // Need to specify key and cer
            // To generate certs I use command: openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
            // And: openssl req -new -x509 -key key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3650
        //}
    });
}
exports.browserSync = browserSyncTask;

// Watch function for catch changes in files 
function watch(){
    gulp.watch( styleWATCH, style );
    gulp.watch( jsWATCH, js);
}

// Gulp default task for default command in console. ( gulp )
// Thx this I have not to run every command separatly but all
// defined runs at once.
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel([
    style, 
    js,
    browserSyncTask,
    watch,
]));
```

My guess is that browserSync is not implemented right and I have some missconfiguration in my code. But don´t really know where it could be. Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try running the browser-sync task inside of your watch task,

```
// Watch function for catch changes in files 
function watch(){
  gulp.watch( styleWATCH, style );
  gulp.watch( jsWATCH, js);

  // run your browser-sync task here
  browserSyncTask();
}

// Gulp default task for default command in console. ( gulp )
// Thx this I have not to run every command separatly but all
// defined runs at once.
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel([
  style, 
  js,
  watch,
]));
```

also you might like this [gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate)